# Achieve button on top of card in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to achieve a button on the top of my card, basically overlapping the card

I tried inserting a button above the card and try to adjust the margin so that it goes to the area I want it, however the margin top will push dow everything on the page

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-lg " style="margin-left:600px; margin-top:10px">
    Large button
</button>


<div class="card-deck card-info card-width">

  <div class="card special-card">

    <h1 class="card-title text-center">COMMERCIAL</h1>
    <img class="card-img-top" src="assets/img/com.png" alt="Card image cap">
    <div class="card-body">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
       <ul>[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Yes thanks. I was able to figure it out with your help. Got it in the exact position I wanted. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using `position:absolute` and `z-index` to position the button on top of the card.

Here's how it works.

`z-index` allows you to place an element on top of other elements. The default `z-index` is zero, so any number greater than that will be on top. *However,* note that Bootstrap uses `z-index` a lot -- so there are probably already some z-index values in use.

`position:absolute` takes an element out of the flow and allows you to place it on top of other elements.  We generally use `position:absolute` together with `z-index`.

Important: You cannot use `position:absolute` unless the parent container has `position:relative` (or `absolute` or `fixed`). The default `position` value is `static`, and that will not work with `position:absolute` in a child element.

DEMO:

```css
.outerDiv {position:relative;}
.d1{width:150px;height:80px;background:wheat;}
button{position:absolute;top:10px;left:20px;}
```

```html
<!-- z-index not needed here because the button comes after the div -->
<div class="outerDiv">
    <div class="d1">Div One</div>
    <button>Button</button>
</div>
```